# mysql returns the date in this format "yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z" I want it in "yyyy-dd-mm" format

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, date, date-formatting

so I am using MySQL as the database for my node app I can insert the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format but when I get data from it returns it as `yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z` so I want only the first part

```js
db.query(`SELECT agereement_date FROM mt_A1 WHERE ledger_num = 15`,(err,data)=>{
  console.log(data)

})
```

the output is like this

```js
[
  RowDataPacket {
    agereement_date: 2021-03-07T18:30:00.000Z,
  }
]
```

I Want only the `YYYY-MM-DD` the first part I am using some JavaScript to rectify it but it feels unnecessary is there a way to get the date in that format directly from MySQL

Comment: Your question mentions zero `00:00:00` time but your example data shows `18:30`. What hapens if you use `SELECT DATE(agereement_date) agereement_date` in your query to get just the date and not the time from your column? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: *but when I get data from it returns it as yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z* MySQL returns the date value in such format NEVER. This is Node.JS interpretation of returned value. *I Want only the YYYY-MM-DD* You may use `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(agereement_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS agereement_date ..` - this converts the value to string type which won't processed by your language additionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time in MySQL db is in without definition of timezone.

NodeJS converts time to `Date` object when You get it from server.

So there are 3 solutions depending on Your use case:

1. if You don't care timezone of browser: You can add `DATE_FORMAT` to sql query and take date part only.
2. it's still not timezone aware, but You can take date from db on backend and cut date part of it using:

```js
db.query('SELECT agereement_date FROM mt_A1 WHERE ledger_num = 15', (err,data) => {

  data = data.map(row => {
    row.agereement_date = row.agereement_date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    
    return row;
  });
  
  console.log(data);
})
```

3. If You want to show correct time for timezone of browser then You must work with that date object on frontend level:

```js
function strftime(sFormat, date) {
  if (!(date instanceof Date)) date = new Date();
  var nDay = date.getDay(),
    nDate = date.getDate(),
    nMonth = date.getMonth(),
    nYear = date.getFullYear(),
    nHour = date.getHours(),
    aDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    aMonths = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    aDayCount = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334],
    isLeapYear = function() {
      if ((nYear&3)!==0) return false;
      return nYear%100!==0 || nYear%400===0;
    },
    getThursday = function() {
      var target = new Date(date);
      target.setDate(nDate - ((nDay+6)%7) + 3);
      return target;
    },
    zeroPad = function(nNum, nPad) {
      return ('' + (Math.pow(10, nPad) + nNum)).slice(1);
    };
  return sFormat.replace(/%[a-z]/gi, function(sMatch) {
    return {
      '%a': aDays[nDay].slice(0,3),
      '%A': aDays[nDay],
      '%b': aMonths[nMonth].slice(0,3),
      '%B': aMonths[nMonth],
      '%c': date.toUTCString(),
      '%C': Math.floor(nYear/100),
      '%d': zeroPad(nDate, 2),
      '%e': nDate,
      '%F': date.toISOString().slice(0,10),
      '%G': getThursday().getFullYear(),
      '%g': ('' + getThursday().getFullYear()).slice(2),
      '%H': zeroPad(nHour, 2),
      '%I': zeroPad((nHour+11)%12 + 1, 2),
      '%j': zeroPad(aDayCount[nMonth] + nDate + ((nMonth>1 && isLeapYear()) ? 1 : 0), 3),
      '%k': '' + nHour,
      '%l': (nHour+11)%12 + 1,
      '%m': zeroPad(nMonth + 1, 2),
      '%M': zeroPad(date.getMinutes(), 2),
      '%p': (nHour<12) ? 'AM' : 'PM',
      '%P': (nHour<12) ? 'am' : 'pm',
      '%s': Math.round(date.getTime()/1000),
      '%S': zeroPad(date.getSeconds(), 2),
      '%u': nDay || 7,
      '%V': (function() {
              var target = getThursday(),
                n1stThu = target.valueOf();
              target.setMonth(0, 1);
              var nJan1 = target.getDay();
              if (nJan1!==4) target.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4-nJan1)+7)%7);
              return zeroPad(1 + Math.ceil((n1stThu-target)/604800000), 2);
            })(),
      '%w': '' + nDay,
      '%x': date.toLocaleDateString(),
      '%X': date.toLocaleTimeString(),
      '%y': ('' + nYear).slice(2),
      '%Y': nYear,
      '%z': date.toTimeString().replace(/.+GMT([+-]\d+).+/, '$1'),
      '%Z': date.toTimeString().replace(/.+\((.+?)\)$/, '$1')
    }[sMatch] || sMatch;
  });
}



const time = new Date('2021-03-08T00:30:00.000+02:00');
const localTime = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time);
const localDate = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time);

console.log(localTime)

console.log(localDate)
```

as You can see I've defined in ISO format with `+02:00` so it may return differently depending on time of local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query :

```
SELECT DATE(agereement_date) 
FROM mt_A1 
WHERE ledger_num = 15
```